# C++ fixed-capacity associate container

Tags: c++, dictionary, associative-array, stdmap

I am looking for a container like `std::unordered_map` that does not use any dynamic allocation. I believe this would be the case for any associate container with a fixed number of keys, or even keys that have to be chosen at compile time.

I am not looking for a `constexpr` or compile time hash map because I would like to be able to update the values in the map.

Example use case:

```cpp
FixedCapacityMap<std::string_view, int> fruits {
  {"n_apples", 0},
  {"n_pairs", 0}
}

fruits["n_apples"] += 1;
fruits["n_pairs"] += 1;
```

Does anyone know if such a library exists, and if not how something like this could be implemented?

Comment: "I am not looking for a constexpr or compile time hash map because I would like to be able to update the values in the map." -- If you only want to be able to update the values, but not the keys, then you could have a compile-time map which maps the keys to some kind of reference to the actual values. These references could be indexes into an array of values, pointers or C++ references. That way, you could change the values without actually changing the map.

Comment: Are the keys known at compile time? Also, how many keys (order of magnitude) are we talking about?

Comment: The keys would be known at compile time and provided in the constructor. I’m looking for something general purpose, so fit for different magnitudes of keys, but tbh in my use cases it would be something like 10 to 200 keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a library with this functionality:

https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/frozen

It allows for `constexpr` and `constinit` ordered and unordered maps with (newly added by me) the ability to update values in runtime.

Answer (score 4):

A necessary consequence of the "no dynamic allocation" rule is that the underlying data is embedded in your type, so you need to specify the number of keys as a template parameter as well.

If the keys are known at compile time you can construct a fixed-size hash table over that.

In general, the next best thing is either chained hashing or binary search. Here is a small implementation that uses binary search over a `std::array<std::pair<K,V>, N>`:

```
template <class K, class V, size_t N>
class FixedCapacityMap {
    public:
        using value_type = std::pair<K,V>;
        FixedCapacityMap(std::initializer_list<value_type> init) {
            assert(init.size() == N);
            std::copy(cbegin(init), cend(init), begin(store));
        }

        V& operator[](const K& key) {
            auto it = std::lower_bound(begin(store), end(store), std::pair{key, V()});
            if (it == end(store) || it.first != key)
                throw std::out_of_range(key);
            return it.second;
        }

    private:
        std::array<value_type, N> store;
}
```

Comment: Oh, of course this works! I don’t know why I didn’t think you could just keep the data sorted. I do expect the keys to be known at compile time, so this works.

Comment: I just realized I completely forgot the binary search aspect. Doh!